# htaccess redirection for php files only to another url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect my php files inside a specific folder to another url , the htacess file that i used is working for php files but also with other extensions and for my case i want only php files to be redirected to the new url 
 that's the htaccess:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ml\.mysite1\.com/fr/test2/^(.*\.php)$
   RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My question is about how can i only redirect *.php and not other extension ( jpg, png etc )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third line needs to be changed so that it only matches files with the php extension.

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.php http://mysite2.com/$1.php [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot match Request URI in `%{HTTP_HOST}` condition.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ml\.mysite1\.com$
RewriteRule ^fr/test2/(.+?\.php)$ http://mysite2.com/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: can i ask you why you chose 302 redirection and not 301

Comment: Once we verify it is working fine, one can replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: i'm working on 2 testing server  so that dose'nt matter too much

Comment: Testing server doesn't cache the results, it is the browser that caches it.