# 301 Redirect from .HTML to .PHP only if .PHP file exists using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect .html files to .php using a 301 (permanent) redirect, but only if the corresponding .php file exists.  I'd like to do this using .htaccess, since I an easily stick one of those in the root directory of the site.

I've seen other similar solutions, but they haven't worked for me or they would always redirect .html to .php, even if the .php file didn't exist.  I still have some .html files that should not be directed to .php, so that requirement is critical.  Server is running Apache 2.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirection for php files only to another url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600684/htaccess-redirection-for-php-files-only-to-another-url)

Comment: What you ask is straight forward: a condition, a rule. Since you claim that no existing solution worked for you I wonder why not? And what you actually tried? Without you telling us, how do you expect us to help?